# How to work with gigantic list with jaro-winkler similarity check

Tags: list, arraylist, jaro-winkler

I have a list with more than 10 million strings that I need to iterate and get scored percentage points while using a similarity function.
I do this by getting an item from another list that will be used to check similarity from the giga list as follows..

```
similarities = []
del similarities[:]
i = 0
drugs ['amoxil', 'acyclovir', 'univir', ...]
while i < len(drugs):
    for idx, item in enumerate(drugs):        
        similarity1 = jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(text1,item)*100
        similarity2 = jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(text2,item)*100
        similarity3 = jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(text3,item)*100
        similarity4 = jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(textn..,item)*100
        similarityn..= ..


        similarities.append(similarity1)
    i += 1
    return similarities
```

The texts (text1, text2, etc) to be used are about 50 to 100. The code works well and fast if drug list has 10 or so items. The more items I add, the slower and more problematic it becomes and can take the laptop to freeze if i have 500k items. I have more than 10 Million items to be used in drug list.
How can I make this faster without crashing the system?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [batch_jaro_winkler](https://github.com/dbousque/batch_jaro_winkler). I created it for use cases similar to this one, where you want maximum performance. You build a *model* that you can then reuse for any number of runtime calculations. Pass your `drugs` or your `texts` as argument to `build_exportable_model`, whatever is the bigger list.

```py
import batch_jaro_winkler as bjw

drugs = ['amoxil', 'acyclovir', 'univir', ...]
exportable_model = bjw.build_exportable_model(drugs)
runtime_model = bjw.build_runtime_model(exportable_model)
for text in ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']:
  similarities = bjw.jaro_winkler_distance(runtime_model, text)
  # similarities = [('amoxil', 0.0), ('acyclovir', 0.5), ('univir', 0.96)]
```

If you only care about the best results and/or results matching with at least a certain score, I highly recommend passing `min_score` and `n_best_results` as argument to `bjw.jaro_winkler_distance`.

Comment: This is great. Thank you!!